# How to remove the pods of a removed nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have removed and delete a node from k8s cluster using the following commands:

`kubectl drain worker1 --ignore-daemonsets`

`kubectl delete worker1`

After that, I saw the kube-proxy and the weave daemonset(both for worker1) still existed (it is expected since I ignored the daemonset)even the nodes is drained and deleted.

How can I remove these pods if the node(worker1) is drained and deleted.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Find out the name of the pod which is scheduled on that deleted node and delete the pod using `kubectl delete pods <pod_name> --grace-period=0 --force -n <namespace>`

Use below command to display more details about pod including the node on which the pod is scheduled

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace> -o wide
```

You could also use `kubeadm reset` on that node. Please note this will uninstall and remove all Kubernetes related software from that node.

Comment: Thx for your input. I used " kubeadm reset" in the removed nodes, the pods like kube-proxy were removed

Comment: Well..that's a bigger hammer..I have edited the answer to add this point